# Ways of asking someone to move over

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice, sentence-request

Could you please let me know how the two short request sentences below differ when it comes to ask someone to move over?

> [**Stand** aside](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/stand-aside) please. 
> [**Step** aside](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/step-aside) please.

I cannot explain the reason, but I have an intuition that "step aside" means move one step over while "stand aside" lacks such a connotation to me.

Also, I was wondering how shall one ask someone to sit a little over when he/she is sitting too close you that you feel uncomfortable?

> Could you please **sit over**? 
> Could you please **sit a little over**? 
> Could you please **sit aside**? 
> Could you please **sit a little aside**?

These sentences all work for me logically and grammatically, but I have no idea if they are idiomatically natural as well.

Comment: Neither **sit over** nor **sit aside** is idiomatic to me. If someone is sitting, I'd use **move over** or **move down**. If you're being extremely informal, [**scooch over**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scooch+over).

Comment: If I needed someone to "stand aside", I would start with "Excuse me,", followed by the reason I need them to do so. In the sitting case, I would start with "Not so close, please."

Comment: For the first example, you may be thinking a bit to literally because stand aside means basically the same (albeit in a slightly firmer tone) as step aside. Most native English speakers would know that if you told them to step aside, they would just stand aside and move out of your way.

Comment: What does it mean @Joe Kerr. Do you mean that it would be safer to just say: "step aside" rather than "stand aside" which is harsher or somehow an impolite way to say: "step aside"?

Comment: @A-friend I believe that neither is unsafe unless it is used in a threatening context. Stand aside is just a different way of saying step aside.

Comment: Thank you very much Joe. Just that was much better if you could assemble all your statements in an answer so that I could accept it. That would be far more time-consuming for other learners to find the answer immediately.